# How to remove the empty last line in the output?

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to solve [a particular problem at hackerrank](http://hackerrank.com/challenges/30-dictionaries-and-maps/problem).

To solve that, I have created a dictionary using hashmap and I want to search the phone number using the name of the person. If there is an entry with that name, print the number with the name else print not found.

```
public static void main(String []args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    Map<String,Integer> map= new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        String name = scan.next();
        int phone = scan.nextInt();
        // Write code here

        map.put(name,phone);   
    }
     while(scan.hasNext()){

         String s = scan.next();
        // Write code here

        if(map.containsKey(s)){
        System.out.println(s+"="+map.get(s));
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Not Found");
        }

    }   
    scan.close();
}
```

I am getting the desired output but with an extra empty line. 
For example, when I search for name 'J' and 'K',and only J is present in the dictionary,my output is:

> ```
> J=88888
> Not Found
> *empty line*
> ```

Comment: Can you please provide what are your inputs ?

Comment: n is number of entries, name and phone is the people's name and phone number respectively , and s is the name we want to search.

Comment: I'm using an online editor.I just have to submit the code and then click on run.The inputs are taken automatically to check whether the code is right or not and just because of this extra line I'm not able to pass the test cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is that, you are getting wrong answer in the online judge because of simple typo. You wrote:

```
System.out.println("Not Found");
```

But the online judge requirement is `Not found`. So, it sould be:

```
System.out.println("Not found");
```

At this point, you'll be getting right answer in the online judge, that's true. But, whatever the question title suggests is a real problem in this case, i.e. you are really getting an extra line at the end. Maybe, that online judge is ignoring extra line check after it finds the correct answer.

Now, to solve the issue, your while loop should be like this:

```
while (in.hasNext()) {
    String s = in.next();  
    if (map.containsKey(s))
        System.out.print(s + "=" + map.get(s));
    else
        System.out.print("Not found");
    if (in.hasNext())
        System.out.println();
}
```

By this extra checking with if statement, you are printing new line after all outputs except the last one.

Comment: Yeah,It was just because of the typo and I noticed it too late. And removing that extra line was my problem anyways and it is gone now. So,Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the putput using `System.out.println`, therfore, a new line will be printed after your message.

If you don't want this behaviour, use `System.out.print`.

Regards.

Comment: I've tried this. Yeah it doesn't give any extra lines in the output but then the result of different inputs are concatenated together. It doesn't really look good that way.